# Is there a way to get tooltip for parts of a string?

Tags: string-manipulation, dataset

Is there a way to get the tooltip to appear for parts of a string?

```
"some string "<>ToString@Tooltip["abbreviation","expanded form"]<>" string continued"
```

Note I am aware of the following strategy.

```
Row[{"some string ",Tooltip["abbreviation","expanded form"]," string continued"}]
```

But this string needs to form the key of a nested `Association`. So unless it is a `String` the `Dataset` does not render in rectangular form.

I believe this can be done by rendering the appropriate boxes inside the string.

Comment: The thought of intentionally using the string box form makes me a little bit queasy :| It's useful and powerful, but there are sooo many potential pitfalls if you ever want to post-process these strings (or really do anything with them)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `StandardForm` in the second argument of `ToString`:

```
"some string " <>  ToString[Tooltip["abbreviation", "expanded form"], StandardForm] <> 
 " string continued"
```

[image]